# Sorting via dropdown and updating the querystring

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

For paging I have this code which enables me to update the querystring without losing any elements in the querystring.

```
var tRVD = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);

foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
   tRVD[key] = Request.QueryString[key];
}

tRVD["page"] = @i;
@Html.ActionLink(@i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Index", tRVD);
```

I need to do the same with sorting.  I have the following code but of course the querystring is overwritten by sortby.  What I need is the same as I have for paging, something that just adds sortby to the querstring if it is not there and updates it if it is.  How is this possible?

```
<form name="sortbyformtop">
   <select onchange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" name="sortbyselecttop">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="sortby=accommodationtype">Accommodation type</option>
      <option value="sortby=mostreviewed">Most reviewed</option>
      <option value="sortby=lowestprice">Lowest price</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve is setting the querystring to the same value as it is now plus sortby.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question nor what you are trying to achieve. Could you please provide a little more context to your question and details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `<input type="hidden">` to your form for each value in the querystring.